# Getting "Warning: Invalid supplied for foreach" when displaying csv file with php

Tags: php

I have to make sure that [this file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=83370130098582331287) is displayed in a html table with php using the code below. When, however, I run the code I, get the following warning:

> Warning: Invalid supplied for foreach () in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/index.php on line 18

How do I solve this?

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {

   if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {

        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else {
                 //Print file details
             echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
             echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
             echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
              $data = [];
             foreach ($_FILES["file"]["name"] as $line) {
              $data[] = str_getcsv($line); /* <-- ERROR LINE */

               }
            }       
     } else {
             echo "No file selected <br />";
     }
    }
?>

<table width="600">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<tr>
<td width="20%">Select file</td>
<td width="80%"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Submit</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: `foreach( file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) as $line )` ?

Answer (score 0):

in Action call display.php
display.php

```
<?php 
 $filename=$_GET['filename'];
 echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
 $f = fopen($filename, "r");
 while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
   echo "<tr>";
   foreach ($line as $cell) {
   echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
  }    
   echo "</tr>\n";
 }
 fclose($f);
 echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```